# XHTML bold numbering of list <li>

Tags: css, xhtml

I am using Document X! Helpstudio and i want to make a list <li> as a header of each section of the documentation that i write. Is it possible to make bold the numbering as well? I try to use CSS but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) can help you achieve that without having to manually write the numbers within `<b>` tags.

I wrote some code for you, check it out yourself.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: list-counter;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: .5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  counter-increment: list-counter;
  content: counter(list-counter) "."; 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by Mr Lister, I slightly modified the CSS so that the space occupied by the number (bullet) couldn't affect the structure and readability.

Comment: Better to use `right:100%` where you have `left:-1em`, so the width of the number won't matter.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about that. Just updated the answer implementing what you shared. I added a margin too to the pseudo-element for better spacing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear what you are asking, and I do not have enough rep to simply comment.

But if i understand it correctly, you can place the numbering between `<b>` tags to make them bold. You can also put then between `<span>` and use `font-weight: bold;` to make them bold.

edit:

your  `<li>` tags would look like this:

```
<li><b>1.</b> Some text</li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah i know this is the easy way but i would like to do without writing the number manually

Comment: then you might want to look at PHP or a framework like AngularJS to do so. As far as I know you cannot add numbers dynamically in pure HTMl and CSS.